# How to select from dynamic table name

Tags: mysql, select, dynamic

I have tables like

```
changes201101
changes201102
changes201103
...
changes201201
```

And table
`whichchanges` which contain rows Year and MONTH

How I can select * from changes from `whichchanges`?

I type this query

```
SET @b := SELECT CONCAT('changes',year,month) FROM whichchanges;
((((@b should contain now multiple rows of changesYearMonth)))))
SET @x := SELECT * FROM @b;
Prepare stmt FROM @b;
Prepare stmt FROM @x;
Execute stmt;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT('changes',year,month) FROM changes)' at line 1

Comment: Looks like you edited your question. Now the query doesn't fit to your error message any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You open 1 `(` and close 2 `)`. Remove the last:

```
SELECT CONCAT('changes',year,month) FROM changes
```

### Edit

the second statement should probably be

```
SET @x := SELECT * FROM (@b) as b;
```

That works, but not sure if that is what you want:

```
SET @b := 'SELECT CONCAT(''changes'',`year`,`month`) FROM whichchanges';
SET @x := 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(''changes'',`year`,`month`) FROM whichchanges) as b';
Prepare stmt FROM @b;
Prepare stmt FROM @x;
Execute stmt;
```

### Edit2

If I understood you right you are looking for that single query:

```
select * from changes
where change_column in (select distinct concat(`year`, `month`) from whichchanges)
```

### Edit3

```
select @b := group_concat(concat(' select * from changes', `year`, `month`, ' union ') separator ' ') as w from whichchanges;
set @b := left(@b, length(@b) - 6);

Prepare stmt FROM @b;
Execute stmt;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d23e/20)

Comment: `SET @b = SELECT CONCAT('change',year,month) FROM whichchanges;
SET @x := SELECT * FROM (@b);
Prepare stmt FROM @b;
Prepare stmt FROM @x;
Execute stmt;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT('changes',year,month) FROM whichchanges' at line 1`

Comment: if i use 

`"SET @b = (SELECT CONCAT('changes',year,month) FROM whichchanges);"

**#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row `**

if i use 

`SET @b = (SELECT CONCAT('changes',year,month) FROM whichchanges LIMIT 1);`

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM (@b)' at line 1**

Comment: i hope this will help http://i.imgur.com/hni0g.jpg
if not, I'll do it by using PHP

Comment: @jurgen-d, yep, it must be in one query but what is "change_column" in your query? 
I think that query should be something like

"select * from changes where changes in (select distinct concat('changes ',`yer`, `month`) from whichchanges)"

**#1146 - Table 'database.changes' doesn't exist**

Comment: You should replace `change_column` with the column name that holds the values in format `201201` of your `changes` table.

Comment: @breq: See this [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/109e4/1). Is that correct? If not, correct it and post back the SQLFiddle link.

Comment: @breq: See my last update with [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d23e/20) example.

Comment: last questions, why i've got comma between union and select? it does not work on my pc :/
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' select * from changes200804 union , select * from changes200805 union , select * ' at line 1**
i've change tab names on my pc, but on sqlfiddle it work fine with my real tab names

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10977/discussion-between-breq-and-juergen-d)