# Using variable name as a table name in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following arrangement of tables (tableX and tableY) are in similar pattern. And when i mean `{object.table}` I would like to have the real table there instead of a string. What now I do is I execute the following SQL for each entry in Object table. But I would like to know is there any SQL solution where I can do this is a single query.

```
SELECT
    persons.person_id AS "person_id",
    {object.table}.avl AS "available",
    "{object.variable_name}" AS "variable_name",
FROM
    persons
INNER JOIN {object.table} ON {object.table}.person_id = persons.person_id
WHERE
    {object.table}.{object.column} = {object.code};

Object
- table (tableX, tableY)
- column
- code
- variable_name

tableX
- person_id
- more_info

persons
- person_id
```

Comment: Maybe you can simply do this with a `UNION`, perhaps you want the MySQL variant of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html, but I really couldn't tell, since I don't understand at all what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: My table "Object" contains two strings which are table and column. This conatains a name of a table in the database and name of a coumn in that table. I need to use them together and get the outcome. But Since its kind of dynamic data I dont know how to use it in MySql

Comment: You should be able to do it with what they call prepared statements in MySQL. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10480456/2947592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use table name and column name as parameter in your query; that's not possible. Table names and column names can't be dynamic in a SQL query.

But it can be achievable programmatically using `PREPARED` query and  a nice example is just given here with code sample 
[Can I use a dynamic table name in stored procedure](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,126506,126598#msg-126598)