# Using SELECT result as a column name in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the fastest way to delete all records in every table of the database with `id = 0`?

It would be simple if every table had its first column called `id`, but in my case one table has first column named `id_tag`, other table - `id_product`, etc.

I've figured out that I can get the name of the first column by:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ps_tag' LIMIT 1
```

but how can I include it in a `DELETE` query? I need something like:

```
DELETE FROM 'ps_tag' WHERE [first_column] = 0
```

My first idea was:

```
DELETE FROM 'ps_tag' 
             WHERE (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ps_tag' LIMIT 1) = 0
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: You're going to have to dynamically build the statement.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480429/how-to-select-from-dynamic-table-name

Comment: well, anything faster than manual edit of each table is good

Comment: As mentioned you are going to have to create SQL text that you run later. If i was given this to do. Hmm, how many records are we looking at? I would generate two queries for each table. 1) select all the rows that will be deleted into a 'related temporary table'. 2) Delete the rows in that table. Easy to restore if anything goes awry.

Comment: A manual edit may be faster than figuriing out something clever.  Plus, evn if you do achieve something clever with dynamic sql, you might still have foreign key problems if you don't run your queries in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can set up a dynamic SQL statement, I often find this type of operation is easier to do in Excel. Write a query to get the column name and table name for the ones you are interested in.

Then, load these into Excel.

In another cell, put in a string like `'delete from @table where @column = 1'`.

Then put in the formula:

```
=substitute(substitute(<where the string is>, '@table', <tablename>), '@column', <columnname>))
```

Copy the code back to your database interface and execute it.

(And any spreadsheet will do. I usually have Excel handy.)