# MYSQL dynamic table name select with join and criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

If I have this schema

- lists (***lead_id***, list_id, campaign_id, ...)
- campaign (campaign_id, ...)
- custom_list_id (lead_id, ...)

there are many tables with name `custom_`*`list_id`* for various *`list_id`* s and I want to:

```
SELECT * from lists ls inner join campaign c ON c.id=ls.campaign_id
inner join custom_"@LISTID" cll ON ls.lead_id = cll.lead_id
```

How do I write this query?
thnx

Comment: Please give more context and an [mcve] for what you have so far.

Comment: you will have to go for `dynamic query`

Comment: hey , thnx for reply !!! i want to select data in dynamic table with the result of query :; SELECT * , SET @s = CONCAT('custom_',vc.list_id) FROM vicidial_lists vc
LEFT JOIN campaign c ON c.id = vc.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN @s ON @s.lead_id = vc.lead_id
WHERE vc.campaign_id='test'

Comment: there are many tables with name custom_list_id - I don't understand this statement

Comment: custom_ is a prefix of many tables, + l'id of list created dynamically

Comment: nearly Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480429/how-to-select-from-dynamic-table-name

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what sql you really want, but try this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'INNER JOIN custom_',  list_id, 'cll', list_id, ' ON ls.lead_id = cll', list_id '.lead_id')
    )
    SEPARATOR ' '
  ) INTO @sql
FROM lists ;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * from lists ls inner join campaign c ON c.id=ls.campaign_id ', @sql);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```